# Getting error : Transition Rejection($id: 0 type: 6, message: The transition errored, detail: TypeError: this.parent.parameters is not a function)

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, ngroute, angularjs-ng-route, angular-ui-router-extras

Getting error : Transition Rejection($id: 0 type: 6, message: The transition errored, detail: TypeError: this.parent.parameters is not a function)

I'm upgrading angualrjs 1.5 to angularjs 1.8.2
Because of angualr js i have to upgrade angular-ui-router from 0.2.18 to 1.0.0
aslo using ui-router-extras 0.0.14
after upgrade, I started getting an error

And we are using state routing

```
 $stateProvider
            .state('mobile-login',
                {
                    url : "/mobile-login",
                    templateUrl : "assets/myorg/mobile/login/login.html",
                    controller:   "loginController",
                    authenticate: false
                })
            .state('mobile-main',
                {
                    url:          "/mobile-main",
                    templateUrl:  "assets/myorg/mobile/main/main.html",
                    controller:   "MainController",
                    authenticate: true
                })
            .state('login',
                {
                    url : "/login",
                    templateUrl : "assets/myorg/login/login.html",
                    controller:   "loginController",
                    authenticate: false,
                    params : {}
                })
```

And to access any state we are using $state.go('xyz')
for example

```
$state.go('login')
```

[image]

this.parent.parmeters() is undefined.

[image]

could you please let me know the quick fix for this.